# how to convert a List of Data to json

Tags: java, json

I want the following json ,where `List<form>` will have list of `form_id`,`form_name`, how can I convert this using jsonobject, I am not getting the proper json output. Please help me with this.
Json:

```
{
    "forms": [
        { "form_id": "1", "form_name": "test1" },
        { "form_id": "2", "form_name": "test2" } 
    ]
}
```

The above is the json structure that i need it for a list.Where id ,name is a list from form object

```
public static JSONObject getJsonFromMyFormObject(List<Form> form) {
    JSONObject responseDetailsJson = new JSONObject();
    JSONArray jsonArray = null;
    System.out.println(form.size());
    for (int i = 0; i < form.size(); i++) {
        JSONObject formDetailsJson = new JSONObject();
        formDetailsJson.put("form_id", form.get(i).getId());
        formDetailsJson.put("form_name", form.get(i).getName());
        jsonArray = new JSONArray();
        jsonArray.add(formDetailsJson);
    }
    responseDetailsJson.put("form", jsonArray);
    return responseDetailsJson;

}
```

Facing issue here not getting output as a list

Comment: you need key or just value like if you need key "form_id" or without just store the value in list like 1, 2 and test1 and test2

Comment: Use [GSON](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/)

Comment: You can use GSON like this >> [1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15332888/3920648


It work for me

Answer (score 5):

The code in the original question is close to achieving the described desired result.  Just move the `JSONArray` instance creation outside of the loop.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;

public class Foo
{
  public static JSONObject getJsonFromMyFormObject(List<Form> form)
  {
    JSONObject responseDetailsJson = new JSONObject();
    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();

    for (int i = 0; i < form.size(); i++)
    {
      JSONObject formDetailsJson = new JSONObject();
      formDetailsJson.put("form_id", form.get(i).getId());
      formDetailsJson.put("form_name", form.get(i).getName());

      jsonArray.add(formDetailsJson);
    }
    responseDetailsJson.put("forms", jsonArray);
    return responseDetailsJson;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    List<Form> forms = new ArrayList<Form>();
    forms.add(new Form("1", "test1"));
    forms.add(new Form("2", "test2"));

    JSONObject jsonObject = getJsonFromMyFormObject(forms);
    System.out.println(jsonObject);
  }
}

class Form
{
  String id;
  String name;

  Form(String i, String n)
  {
    id = i;
    name = n;
  }

  String getId()
  {
    return id;
  }

  String getName()
  {
    return name;
  }
}
```

Comment: BinaryNights remarked that an API he looked at did not provide a method named "put" for JSONArrays, but rather provided a method named "add".  The API I used in the example above did indeed provide a "put" method, and this code was compiled and verified to produce the stated outcome.

Answer (score 2):

Properbly http://www.roseindia.net/tutorials/json/jsonobject-java-example.shtml will help.

According the comment from Tushar, here the extract from the aboved linked website:

> Now in this part you will study how to use JSON in Java. 
>   To have functionality of JSON in java you must have JSON-lib. JSON-lib also
>   requires following "JAR" files:
>
> 1. commons-lang.jar
> 2. commons-beanutils.jar
> 3. commons-collections.jar
> 4. commons-logging.jar
> 5. ezmorph.jar
> 6. json-lib-2.2.2-jdk15.jar
>
> JSON-lib is a java library for that transforms beans, collections, maps, java arrays and XML to JSON and
>   then for retransforming them back to beans, collections, maps and
>   others.   In this example we are going to use JSONObject class for
>   creating an object of JSONObject and then we will print these object
>   value. For using JSONObject class we have to import following package
>   "net.sf.json". To add elements in this object we have used put()
>   method. Here is the full example code of FirstJSONJava.java is as
>   follows:

**FirstJSONJava.java**

```
    import net.sf.json.JSONObject;

    public class FirstJSONJava
    {
       public static void main(String args[])
       {
        JSONObject object=new JSONObject();
         object.put("name","Amit Kumar");
        object.put("Max.Marks",new Integer(100));
        object.put("Min.Marks",new Double(40));
        object.put("Scored",new Double(66.67));
        object.put("nickname","Amit");
        System.out.println(object);
      }
   }
```

> To run this example you have to follow these few steps as follows:
>
> - [Download JSON-lib jar and other supporting Jars](http://www.roseindia.net/tutorials/json/JSONLibraries.zip)
> - Add these jars to your classpath
> - Create and save FirstJSONJava.java
> - Compile it and execute it.

Comment: I think , you have to put Code_snippet . ( a month ago i was also advised by a senior , because links are not secure way , they can be removed in future or will break ) !