# How to convert List to Json in Java

Tags: java, json

How to convert generic list to json in Java.I have class like this..

```
public class Output
{
    public int Keyname { get; set; }
    public Object  outputvalue{ get; set; }  //outvalue may be even a object collection
}

List<Output> outputList = new List<Output>();
```

I want to convert outputList  into json in Java.After converting i will send it to client.

Comment: Thats rather difficult if you just know the outputvalue is an `Object`. We can not even assume it is serializable.

Comment: assume all classes is serializable

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to convert a List of Data to json](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8182391/how-to-convert-a-list-of-data-to-json)

Comment: Can you tell us what framwork that you use, such as spring or something else, in some framework that it can do this automatically, and send data to the client browser.

Comment: @vmb - what's the expected output?

Comment: You can use GSON like this >>  http://stackoverflow.com/a/15332888/3920648  it work for me

Answer (score 153, accepted):

Use GSON library for that. Here is the sample code

```
List<String> foo = new ArrayList<String>();
foo.add("A");
foo.add("B");
foo.add("C");

String json = new Gson().toJson(foo );
```

Here is the maven dependency for Gson

```xml
<dependencies>
    <!--  Gson: Java to Json conversion -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Or you can directly download jar from here and put it in your class path

http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/downloads/detail?name=gson-1.0.jar&can=4&q=

To send Json to client you can use spring or in simple servlet add this code

> response.getWriter().write(json);

Comment: How to remove null from the json if the list contain null.

Comment: How does the output look like?

Comment: You should write `new ArrayList<>()` instead of `new ArrayList()`.

Answer (score 14):

You need an external library for this.

```
JSONArray jsonA = JSONArray.fromObject(mybeanList);
System.out.println(jsonA);
```

[Google GSON](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) is one of such libraries

You can also take a look [here](http://www.kodejava.org/browse/59.html) for examples on converting Java object collection to JSON string.

Answer (score 7):

jackson provides very helpful and lightweight API to convert Object to JSON and vise versa. Please find the example code below to perform the operation

```
List<Output> outputList = new ArrayList<Output>();
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        Output output = new Output(1,"2342");
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        String jsonString = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(output);
        System.out.println(jsonString);
    } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

there are many other features and nice documentation for Jackson API. you can refer to the links like: https://www.journaldev.com/2324/jackson-json-java-parser-api-example-tutorial..

dependencies to include in the project are

```
    <!-- Jackson -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
public void test(){
// net.sf.json.JSONObject, net.sf.json.JSONArray    

List objList = new ArrayList();
objList.add("obj1");
objList.add("obj2");
objList.add("obj3");
HashMap objMap = new HashMap();
objMap.put("key1", "value1");
objMap.put("key2", "value2");
objMap.put("key3", "value3");
System.out.println("JSONArray :: "+(JSONArray)JSONSerializer.toJSON(objList));
System.out.println("JSONObject :: "+(JSONObject)JSONSerializer.toJSON(objMap));
}
```

you can find API [here](http://json-lib.sourceforge.net/apidocs/net/sf/json/JSONObject.html).

Answer (score 3):

Look at the [google gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) library.  It provides a rich api for dealing with this and is very straightforward to use.

Comment: @vbm - https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Collections-Examples

Answer (score 3):

download java-json.jar from Java2s 
then use the JSONArray constructor

```
List myList = new ArrayList<>();    
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(myList);
System.out.println(jsonArray);
```

Answer (score 2):

For simplicity and well structured sake, use SpringMVC. It's just so simple.

```
@RequestMapping("/carlist.json")
public @ResponseBody List<String> getCarList() {
    return carService.getAllCars();
}
```

Reference and credit: https://github.com/xvitcoder/spring-mvc-angularjs

Answer (score -1):

Use GSONBuilder with setPrettyPrinting and disableHtml for nice output.

```
String json = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().disableHtmlEscaping().
                            create().toJson(outputList  );
                    fileOut.println(json);
```