# JSON Error in retrieving data

Tags: java, json, jquery, spring-mvc

Here is Client side code:

```
function startAjax() {
    $.ajax({
        type : 'GET',
        url : 'customers/ShowAllCustomers',//this is url mapping for controller
        dataType: 'json', 
        contentType: 'application/json',
        mimeType: 'application/json',
        success : function(response) {
            alert(response.get(0).first_name);
                         //this response is list of object commming from server
        },
        error : function() {
            alert("opps error occured");
        }
    });
}
```

and here is my Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/ShowAllCustomers", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody List<Customer> AllCustomersList() {
        List<Customer> customers= customerService.getAllCustomers();
        return customers;
    }
```

Everytime "oops error occured" alert appears. Can you please point out error in this for me. I will be really thankful......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
List<Customer> customers= customerService.getAllCustomers();
return customers;
```

The above code returns a Java `List` , but the jQuery is expecting a JSON String .

```
dataType: 'json', 
contentType: 'application/json',
mimeType: 'application/json',
```

You need to convert the `List` to a JSON string using some JSON library.

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14228912/how-to-convert-list-to-json-in-java) .

Comment: I have changed by controller, its now looks like this: @RequestMapping(value="/ShowAllCustomers", method = RequestMethod.GET)
 public @ResponseBody String AllCustomersList() {
  List<Customer> customers= customerService.getAllCustomers();
  
  String json_customers = new Gson().toJson(customers);
  return json_customers;
 }
but still not producing desired results;

Comment: consol says: 
 at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:68)
 at

Comment: actually there is no stacktrace. when I give the specified URL then consol gives this message and nothing happends any more.

Comment: sorry sir. but I can't found server log :-(

Comment: I found Server Log. It says: java.lang.StackOverflowError
 at java.lang.StringBuffer.append(Unknown Source)
 at java.io.StringWriter.write(Unknown Source)
 at com.google.gson.stream.JsonWriter.string(JsonWriter.java:519)
 at com.google.gson.stream.JsonWriter.writeDeferredName(JsonWriter.java:387)
 at com.google.gson.stream.JsonWriter.beginArray(JsonWriter.java:280)