# Convert ["100","101"] to {"100","101"} i.e. Print in JSON format

Tags: java, json

I tried with the below code to convert `List<String>` to `String[]`

```
    List<String> input = new ArrayList<String>();
    input.add("100");
    input.add("101");
    System.out.println(input);  
    String[] size = new String[input.size()];
    size = input.toArray(size);
    System.out.println(size);
```

But this one prints as ["100","101"] not as required by me {"100","101"}. . ? I then used GSON to acheive the desired output.

Comment: Do you want to output JSON or just the string in your example?

Comment: I need output in JSON format

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert List to Json in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14228912/how-to-convert-list-to-json-in-java)

Comment: Please note that `{"100","101"}` is not JSON, which consists of `"key" : "value"` mappings. For this reason, converting a list/array to  JSON is ambiguous; there are no keys in a list, only values. Have a look at the above link by Naman for possible solutions.

Answer (score 1):

**In Java the standard output (delegating to `toString()` method) for arrays is always `[items]`**.

If you expect different output, you need to use custom code or library.