# send "POST" list of int

Tags: java, android, json

I have server that takes list of int or one int. When I send int, it works good, but when Im trying send `List<Integer>` or `int[]`, response is error(`code 400`) always. How I can send list of int? Here is my code:

```
  url = new URL(adress);
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            urlConnection.setUseCaches(false);
            urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(10000);
            urlConnection.setReadTimeout(10000);
            urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/json");

      "android.schoolportal.gr");
            urlConnection.connect();

            JSONObject jsonParam = new JSONObject();    
           jsonParam.put("categories_okpd_2", list);
            OutputStreamWriter out = new   OutputStreamWriter(urlConnection.getOutputStream());
            out.write(jsonParam.toString());
            out.close();
```

I tried `list` like a:

```
  int myInt = 1;
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        list.add(myInt);
```

and

```
int[] list = new int[5];
```

but it always results in an error with `code:400`.

Comment: `When I send int, it works good`. Please show that code.

Comment: `jsonParam.toString()`. Please tell what the contens is.

Comment: See this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/34150284/1458740 It's possible that you should specify charset in Content-Type header and encode string in that charset.

Answer (score 1):

HTTP status 400 means bad request: you send to server something, that it can't parse (you send list wrapped in object, and server waits pure list).

At the beginning, try to log json with list at client side.
To send list in json format better to wrap it in a class:

```
{
    "list": [0, 4, 5]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You fist need to parse your list to json and then send it. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14229020/1319519) is a similar answer on how to parse a list to json format.