# How to convert Java object to JSON

Tags: java, json, spring

It is a Spring project. I have a list of objects:

```
List<User> userList = new ArrayList<>();
userList.add(new User("user1", "password1"));
userList.add(new User("user2", "password2"));
userList.add(new User("user3", "password3"));
userList.add(new User("user4", "password4"));
```

How to convert the list to JSON array?

Comment: use `Gson` or `Json` apis.

Comment: That really depends on your framework. Is this a Spring Application? Pure Java?

Comment: It is a "Spring" project

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert List to Json in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14228912/how-to-convert-list-to-json-in-java)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the below dependency to your project:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.7</version>
        </dependency>
```

Then try below code :

```
    List<User> userList = new ArrayList<>();
    userList.add(new User("user1", "password1"));
    userList.add(new User("user2", "password2"));
    userList.add(new User("user3", "password3"));
    userList.add(new User("user4", "password4"));
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    String string = mapper.writeValueAsString(userList);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import java.util.*;
import org.json.simple.*;

// this method converts a list to JSON Array
String jsonStr = JSONArray.toJSONString(userList);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this solution:

```
String json = new Gson().toJson(userList);
```

Here is the maven dependency for Gson:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
    <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.6</version>
</dependency>
```

or download the lib file from here:
https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.8.6/jar

Answer (score 1):

You can convert them to array or object using json. below is a sample code

```
// import packages
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;


// sample code

JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(byteArray);
JSONObject response = (JSONObject) jsonObj.getJSONArray("passwords").get(0);
JSONArray localizedObjectAnnotations = (JSONArray) response.getJSONArray("password1");  // if an array


// you can now iterate to get more data
for (int k = 0; k < localizedObjectAnnotations.length(); k++) {
    JSONObject buttonDetails = (JSONObject) localizedObjectAnnotations.get(k);
    this.tmpItem = new Item();
    this.tmpItem.setName(buttonDetails.get("name").toString());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
List<User> userList = new ArrayList<>();
userList.add(new User("user1", "password1"));
userList.add(new User("user2", "password2"));
userList.add(new User("user3", "password3"));
userList.add(new User("user4", "password4"));

JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(userList );
System.out.println(jsonArray);

For this you need to import:
import org.json.JSONArray;
```