# How to convert list data into json in java

Tags: java, json, list

I have a function which is returning Data as `List` in java class. Now as per my need, I have to convert it into `Json` Format.

Below is my function code snippet:

```
public static List<Product> getCartList() {
    List<Product> cartList = new Vector<Product>(cartMap.keySet().size());
    for(Product p : cartMap.keySet()) {
        cartList.add(p);
    }
    return cartList;
}
```

I tried To convert into `json` by using this code but it is giving type mismatch error as function is of type List...

```
public static List<Product> getCartList() {
    List<Product> cartList = new Vector<Product>(cartMap.keySet().size());
    for(Product p : cartMap.keySet()) {
        cartList.add(p);
    }

    Gson gson = new Gson();
     // convert your list to json
     String jsonCartList = gson.toJson(cartList);
     // print your generated json
     System.out.println("jsonCartList: " + jsonCartList);

     return jsonCartList;

        }
```

Please help me resolve this.

Comment: Use [GSON](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/).

Comment: @vikas See if this helps you - http://www.kodejava.org/examples/588.html

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
public static List<Product> getCartList() {

    JSONObject responseDetailsJson = new JSONObject();
    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();

    List<Product> cartList = new Vector<Product>(cartMap.keySet().size());
    for(Product p : cartMap.keySet()) {
        cartList.add(p);
        JSONObject formDetailsJson = new JSONObject();
        formDetailsJson.put("id", "1");
        formDetailsJson.put("name", "name1");
       jsonArray.add(formDetailsJson);
    }
    responseDetailsJson.put("forms", jsonArray);//Here you can see the data in json format

    return cartList;

}
```

you can get the data in the following form

```
{
    "forms": [
        { "id": "1", "name": "name1" },
        { "id": "2", "name": "name2" } 
    ]
}
```

Comment: thnx sir for ur response ..plz sir tell me what to add in this code: " formDetailsJson.put("...", "...");"

Comment: you need to add related jar files to class path which contain org.json.simple.JSONArray,org.json.simple.JSONObject classes.

Comment: Sir i need to know what to add as argument in this "formDetailsJson.put("...", "...");
        formDetailsJson.put("...", "...");"

Comment: And those jar file i ahave added sir

Comment: you need to put name with which name you are going to access in the javascript

Comment: sir i am trying to do it like this "formDetailsJson.put("title", "description","price");" but its giving error

Answer (score 37):

Using [gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) it is much simpler. Use following code snippet:

```
 // create a new Gson instance
 Gson gson = new Gson();
 // convert your list to json
 String jsonCartList = gson.toJson(cartList);
 // print your generated json
 System.out.println("jsonCartList: " + jsonCartList);
```

#### Converting back from JSON string to your Java object

```
 // Converts JSON string into a List of Product object
 Type type = new TypeToken<List<Product>>(){}.getType();
 List<Product> prodList = gson.fromJson(jsonCartList, type);

 // print your List<Product>
 System.out.println("prodList: " + prodList);
```

Comment: Sir i tried with follwoing code but Giving Type Mismatch error "public static List<Product> getCartList() {
  List<Product> cartList = new Vector<Product>(cartMap.keySet().size());
  for(Product p : cartMap.keySet()) {
   cartList.add(p);
  }
  
  Gson gson = new Gson();
   // convert your list to json
   String jsonCartList = gson.toJson(cartList);
   // print your generated json
   System.out.println("jsonCartList: " + jsonCartList);
   
   return jsonCartList;
  
   }"

Comment: Because function is in List and it is returning string

Comment: Can you change `List<Product> cartList = new Vector<Product>(cartMap.keySet().size());` to this: `List<Product> cartList = new ArrayList<Product>(cartMap.keySet().size());`

Comment: Or better: `List<Product> cartList = new ArrayList<Product>(cartMap.keySet());` then no need to run any for loop.

Comment: Sir it is giving type mismatch error as it is returning string and function is in List

Comment: @Vikas: You were not supposed to stick above code inside `getCartList()` method :) That method is returning `List<Product>` and  let it be. Just where you're calling that method use the returned value and use above gson code snippet to convert returned list from `getCartList()` method to JSON string.

Answer (score 7):

Try these simple steps:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
String newJsonData = mapper.writeValueAsString(cartList);
return newJsonData;
ObjectMapper() is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.ObjectMapper();
```

Answer (score 0):

i wrote my own function to return list of object for populate combo box :

```
public static String getJSONList(java.util.List<Object> list,String kelas,String name, String label) {
        try {
            Object[] args={};
            Class cl = Class.forName(kelas);
            Method getName = cl.getMethod(name, null);
            Method getLabel = cl.getMethod(label, null);
            String json="[";
            for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            Object o = list.get(i);
            if(i>0){
                json+=",";
            }
            json+="{\"label\":\""+getLabel.invoke(o,args)+"\",\"name\":\""+getName.invoke(o,args)+"\"}";
            //System.out.println("Object = " + i+" -> "+o.getNumber());
            }
            json+="]";
            return json;
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(JSONHelper.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("Error in get JSON List");
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return "";
    }
```

and call it from anywhere like :

```
String toreturn=JSONHelper.getJSONList(list, "com.bean.Contact", "getContactID", "getNumber");
```

Comment: Usage += for string is very bad practice in loop

Comment: yup, i just have a little bit data so its not effect that much.. if you work with lot of data you can use StringBuilder or StringBuffer.

Answer (score 0):

Try like below with <kbd>**`Gson`**</kbd> Library.

Earlier Conversion List format were:

```
[Product [Id=1, City=Bengalore, Category=TV, Brand=Samsung, Name=Samsung LED, Type=LED, Size=32 inches, Price=33500.5, Stock=17.0], Product [Id=2, City=Bengalore, Category=TV, Brand=Samsung, Name=Samsung LED, Type=LED, Size=42 inches, Price=41850.0, Stock=9.0]]
```

and here the conversion source begins.

```
//** Note I have created the method toString() in Product class.

//Creating and initializing a java.util.List of Product objects
List<Product> productList = (List<Product>)productRepository.findAll();

//Creating a blank List of Gson library JsonObject
List<JsonObject> entities = new ArrayList<JsonObject>();

//Simply printing productList size
System.out.println("Size of productList is : " + productList.size());

//Creating a Iterator for productList
Iterator<Product> iterator = productList.iterator();

//Run while loop till Product Object exists.
while(iterator.hasNext()){

    //Creating a fresh Gson Object
    Gson gs = new Gson();

    //Converting our Product Object to JsonElement 
    //Object by passing the Product Object String value (iterator.next())
    JsonElement element = gs.fromJson (gs.toJson(iterator.next()), JsonElement.class);

    //Creating JsonObject from JsonElement
    JsonObject jsonObject = element.getAsJsonObject();

    //Collecting the JsonObject to List
    entities.add(jsonObject);

}

//Do what you want to do with Array of JsonObject
System.out.println(entities);
```

Converted Json Result is :

```
[{"Id":1,"City":"Bengalore","Category":"TV","Brand":"Samsung","Name":"Samsung LED","Type":"LED","Size":"32 inches","Price":33500.5,"Stock":17.0}, {"Id":2,"City":"Bengalore","Category":"TV","Brand":"Samsung","Name":"Samsung LED","Type":"LED","Size":"42 inches","Price":41850.0,"Stock":9.0}]
```

Hope this would help many guys!

Answer (score 0):

```
JSONObject responseDetailsJson = new JSONObject();
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();

List<String> ls =new  ArrayList<String>();

for(product cj:cities.getList()) {
    ls.add(cj);
    JSONObject formDetailsJson = new JSONObject();
    formDetailsJson.put("id", cj.id);
    formDetailsJson.put("name", cj.name);
    jsonArray.put(formDetailsJson);
}

responseDetailsJson.put("Cities", jsonArray);

return responseDetailsJson;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following method which uses Jackson library

```
public static <T> List<T> convertToList(String jsonString, Class<T> target) {
    if(StringUtils.isEmpty(jsonString)) return List.of();

        return new ObjectMapper().readValue(jsonString, new ObjectMapper().getTypeFactory().
                constructCollectionType(List.class, target));
    } catch ( JsonProcessingException | JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return List.of();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

if response is of type List , res.toString() is simply enough  to convert to json or else we need to use
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
String jsonRes = mapper.writeValueAsString(res);