# How to create a customized javaScript array?

Tags: javascript, jsp, fullcalendar

I have a little web app. And I use a calender(code from [here FullCalendar](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/)) there inside a .jsp file. 
I use Spring mvc architecture. So when this page loaded a controller which is responsible for this page loading will add an attribute called `calendarEventList` to the `model`. 
'calendarEventList' is an `ArrayList<calObject>`. calObject is a class which contain the details about the even.

I can access those details in the jsp by `${calEvent.eventID}` where `calEvent` is an Object from that ArrayList.

In FullCalendar the event load can be called like below

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
events: [
    {
        title  : 'event1',
        start  : '2010-01-01'
    },
    {
        title  : 'event2',
        start  : '2010-01-05',
        end    : '2010-01-07'
    },
    {
        title  : 'event3',
        start  : '2010-01-09 12:30:00',
        allDay : false // will make the time show
    }
]
});
```

I want is like below

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
   events: //read the `calendarEventList` and create a suitable array 
});
```

I have `title` ,`start` ,`end` .. details in a `Oblect of the calendarEventList`. 
So I want to create the list which I need to give to the `fullcalendar`. How can I create such a kind of array in JS. 
It's structure should match `[{},{},{},...,{},{}]` as given in the example. `{}` includes a detail about one Object in that `calendarEventList` ArrayList.

any detailed description will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If i truly understand your question ( you have array of objects, all objects contains different field, but each object contains title, start (and end)). So your task is filter this array.

Solution:

```
function factory(array){
  return array.map(function(item){ 
    var instance = {title: item.title, start: item.start};
    if(item.end) instance.end = item.end;
    return item;
  });
}
var res = factory([{ item: 1, title: 2, start: 4, an: 123, pp: "asdf"}, { item: 2, title: 2, start: 4, end: 5}, { item: 3, title: 2, start: 4}]);
```

Output will be filtered array of objects with start, title, (end) fields;

Try [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/NLyt4/1/)

Comment: on demo page click run button, open console and see the result!

Comment: The `calendarEventList` is a Java ArrayList list which contain java Objects. To insert data to the `event :` I need to populate a `[{},{},..,{},{}]` like a list. That is what I have to do.I think the format should be match. can you help me with that?

Comment: I think your input to the `factory` function is what I need as my output. `[{ item: 1, title: 2, start: 4}, { item: 2, title: 2, start: 4, end: 5}, { item: 3, title: 2, start: 4}]`

Comment: @prime read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15332733/how-to-convert-list-data-into-json-in-java is about how to convert arraylist to json format

Comment: The `item`, `title` , `start`.. are my values of the Object. I can access them like we access any other java Object attributes like, `calEvent.item` like wise when calEvent is a Object of the `ArrayList`.

Comment: @prime but to working via javascript you must convert to json, only after this you can continue work ))

Comment: I'm using [this](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/events_array/) documentation. It says another way to use `json`. But this is simple array I think. or am I getting it completely wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Let try with my example:

```
 var date = new Date();
 var d = date.getDate();
 var m = date.getMonth();
 var y = date.getFullYear();
 var employees = [];
 employees.push({ id: 111, title: "Testing Event 001", start: new Date(y, m, d-5,10,30) , end: new Date(y, m, d-5,12,30),className: ['yellow-event', 'black-text-event']}); 
 employees.push({ id: 111, title: "Testing Event 002", start: new Date(y, m, d-3,10,30) , end: new Date(y, m, d-3,12,30),className: ['yellow-event', 'black-text-event']});
```

on `events: employees` put like this,,
Hope it help full. thanks you..