# How to return Data from Servlet

Tags: java, jquery, jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets

I have a servlet that is supposed to return a report to a web page, each item in the report is stored in the `alist` List object.

```
out.println(alist); // ArraList of String
```

On the client-side, here is the Javascript code that captures the data from `alist`:

```
$.get('DisplayReport',{reportId:reportId},function(responseTest){
    $("#div1").show();
    for(var i = 0; i < responseTest.length; i++)
    {
        $('#row1').append("<td>"+responseTest[i]+"</td>");
    }
});
```

The problem is that `responseTest[i]` displays each character instead of each item in the list. Please help.

Comment: Dude... a Java list can't be converted to a Javascript list. Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2010990/how-do-you-return-a-json-object-from-a-java-servlet

Comment: what i need to send or write in out.println() , which i can pick from $.get success method

Comment: Can't you convert `ArrayList` object to Json?

Comment: [See this 1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15332733/how-to-convert-list-data-into-json-in-java) [See this 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14228912/how-to-convert-list-to-json-in-java)

Comment: what i will pass from servlet to $.get('servlet')