# Spring JPA Custom Query to return JSON

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I am using Spring hibernate with JPA Repository to return the values as JSON. It works fine for all default cases. I am having a problem with custom query in my CrudRepository to return aggregated values as JSON.

CrudRepository

```
@Repository
public interface ExpenseRepository extends CrudRepository<Expense, Integer>{
    @Query("SELECT min(dtDate) as dtDate ,Max(dtDate) as dtDate FROM Expense")
    Iterable<Expense> getAvlRptDates();
}
```

NOTE: I have tried with and without Alias, List etc as well.

Controller

```
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(value="/getAvlExpMonthYear",method=RequestMethod.GET)
public Iterable<Expense> getAvlRptDates(){
    //String test = testRepo.findAll().toString();
    return expRepo.getAvlRptDates();
}
```

I tried with List as well. I know that converting to JSON with custom code or additional dto classes.

Please let me know if there any easy way without creating additional domain class or dto classes just for two fields.

Comment: If you are returning only two values, why don't you use String array? I assume it will be easy.

Comment: @VimalBera, Thanks for your quick response. Will it return JSON without any additional changes?

Comment: it should return as per http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-responsebody

Comment: It returns as ["2015-01-02,2015-10-04"]. Not a valid JSON. I have similar queries with multiple aggregated functions more. I dont want any additional class just for aggregated queries, but domain class can be modified to add any columns if required.

Comment: @Shamseer `["2015-01-02,2015-10-04"]` is a valid JSON - it's an array with **one** String element - `2015-01-02,2015-10-04`... But I believe it was a typo only (in your comment) and it returned two strings, right? Can you share code for `Expense` class?

Comment: Thanks, It resolved my req... 
I have rewritten the method like this. Iterable<Date> getAvlRptDates(); This will return the JSON.  [["2015-01-02","2015-10-04"]]. The code which consumes it, takes the value of index[0]. So that it can be iterated in a loop.

Answer (score 1):

This will makes json, dependent on class attributes.

```
@GetMapping(value = "/...")
@Query("SELECT min(dtDate) as dtDate ,Max(dtDate) as dtDate FROM Expense")
Expense[] getAvlRptDates();
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
@Repository
public interface ExpenseRepository extends CrudRepository<Expense, Integer>{
    @Query("SELECT min(dtDate) as dtDate ,Max(dtDate) as dtDate FROM Expense")
    Iterable<Expense> getAvlRptDates();
}
```

To the following changing Iterable to Optional which returns a list of Jsons:

```
@Repository
public interface ExpenseRepository extends CrudRepository<Expense, Integer>{
    @Query("SELECT min(dtDate) as dtDate ,Max(dtDate) as dtDate FROM Expense")
    Optional<Expense> getAvlRptDates();
}
```

Now, you will get some sort of JSON but not the kind of json that meets official standards.

So my recommendation is to do:

```
@Repository
public interface ExpenseRepository extends CrudRepository<Expense, Integer>{
    @Query("SELECT min(dtDate) as dtDate ,Max(dtDate) as dtDate FROM Expense")
    Expense[] getAvlRptDates();
}
```

Where it return a single iterable, then convert the contents of the iterable to json one by one. See below link:

[How to convert list data into json in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15332733/how-to-convert-list-data-into-json-in-java)

Hope it helps.