# Convert List<Item> to json

Tags: java, json

I am having a List like following,

```
List<Item> EquipmentData = SAPEquipment.getByFilter(filter);
```

That item is the result I'm getting from SAP ("com.vaadin.data.util.sqlcontainer.RowItem")

My problem is that i need to convert that List to Json format. I've been reading some examples and tried using Gson like that:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
gson.toJson(EquipmentData);
```

also tried with just one item

```
gson.toJson(EquipmentData.get(0));
```

The error reported is the following one:

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
com.google.gson.stream.JsonWriter.string(JsonWriter.java:559)
com.google.gson.stream.JsonWriter.writeDeferredName(JsonWriter.java:402)
com.google.gson.stream.JsonWriter.beginObject(JsonWriter.java:307)
com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:214)
com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:68)
com.google.gson.internal.bind.MapTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(MapTypeAdapterFactory.java:208)
com.google.gson.internal.bind.MapTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(MapTypeAdapterFactory.java:145)
com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:68)
com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:99)
com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:219)
com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:68)
com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:99)
com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:219)
com.google.gson.Gson$FutureTypeAdapter.write(Gson.java:899)
```

I cannot modify that List so I will need a proper way to convert it.

Any tip will be highly appreciated

EDIT : Added Item Class link ([vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/data/Item.html](http://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/data/Item.html))

EDIT2: Added full stacktrace /

Comment: Show the `Item` class, please

Comment: You can see Item Class here: https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/data/Item.html

Comment: Stackoverflow typically occurs when you have Gson thinking an object contains itself, so since I don't know what instance of your Item object looks like, it's hard to say

Comment: Include entire stacktrace.

Comment: Can you please share actual content of "List<Item>"

Comment: @FlorescuGeorgeCătălin added full stacktrace

Comment: `com.vaadin.data.Item` is an interface. What gives you `EquipmentData.get(0).getClass().getName()` ?

Comment: @PeterMmm yes, you are right "com.vaadin.data.util.sqlcontainer.RowItem"

Comment: `RowItem` is a very deep nested object. Probably @cricket_007 is right and at one point is a recursive reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for `Stackoverflow` might be because of the recursive mappings in your **Item** class. One way to fix this is to iterate through the `EquipmentData` list and set your return object(**DTO**) then convert the **DTO** using `GSON`.

Comment: How should I store that temporary object?I think I will not be able to cast my Item to Object

Comment: Do post your `Item` class

Comment: It's a RowItem from Vaadin : https://vaadin.com/api/7.7.3/com/vaadin/data/util/sqlcontainer/RowItem.html

Comment: You will have to create a DTO class that has specific properties you want in `JSON`. Once you have that set those properties by iterating through your list `EquipmentData` change it to `JSON` using `GSON`

Answer (score 1):

Iterate each item in the list and add it into a JSON object. Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15332733/how-to-convert-list-data-into-json-in-java) answer.

Comment: please describe the essence of the the attached answer. Otherwise your answer will appear in the Low Quality Posts Review Queue and will probably get deleted.